# Create Directory when my application installed first time

Tags: android

I want a develop simple app in which i have to check at the time of my app installation that directory that i create in my app is already exist before the app is installed, if yes then i have to remove that directory and create new directory in the sdcard.

I am able to do it at installation time but the actual problem is that i put that code in my main activity so when i reopen my app at that time directory is deleted also , so that i don't wont to do because i have put data on that after first installation .

If anyone know the way then please tell me ..

Kind regards,
Jalp.

Answer (score 0):

```
    File wallpaperDirectory = new File("/sdcard/dirname/");
                // have the object build the directory structure, if
                // needed.

    if(!wallpaperDirectory.exists())
    { wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();}
```

please try this

Comment: i said that i successfully create the directory and delete but when i reopen my app it is deleted again , that i don't want ... HOw to do it ?

Comment: ya, i can solve, it just show me your code, i will give you suggestion for it

Comment: Please try this code now i edited and let me know if u have any doubt

Answer (score 0):

```
File dir = new File("/sdcard/dirname/");
if(!(dir.isDirectory() || dir.exists())) dir.mkdirs();
```

Comment: hey i have done through sharedpreferences ... Thanks for your reply